# Basic excercise for warming up on C#

Tags: c#, console, exe

I started to learn C# a week ago and I'm getting familiarized with the working environment. So far we've learned the usual stuff: variable types, function declarations, how to compile a project, etc.

As the first assignment our teacher gave us a screen capture of how we are supposed to pass arguments to a executable file.

[image]

I read that`string[] args` is what is used for "grabbing" from the console and passing on to the rest of the code. However when I try to print like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(args);
```

I always get the same result:

[image: error]

How can I pass a parameter to the exe file via the console?

Comment: When you print `args`, you're printing the object type, which is a `String[]`. Instead, you want to print the contents of that array, which you can do by iterating through it and printing each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console is outputting the entire string array object as a string (`System.String[]`). To see its contents you need to iterate through the array:

```
foreach (string s in args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

This will show you the contents of the array. The `[0]` value will always be the name of the executable, and your parameters will start at position `[1]`.